# asp.net MVC page failing on webserver but runs fine on local machine

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am creating a web application in MVC and when it runs locally it is fine. I recently deployed it to Azure and I encountered a few problems. I had created an Area and forgot to add a web.config file and _viewStart.cshtml.

Once these files were added the application has been working fine except for a page. When I navigate to the edit page the page displays “An error occurred whilst processing the request” where the renderbody() section would go.

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult EditTest(int? id)
    {
    if (id == null)
    {
       return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    } 

    ROUND_DETAILS rOUND_DETAILS = db.ROUND_DETAILS.Find(id);
    if (rOUND_DETAILS == null)
    {
       return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(rOUND_DETAILS);
   }
```

View (smaller version)

```
@model TM470FinalProject.Areas.GolfApp.Models.ROUND_DETAILS

@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
 }

<h2>Edit</h2>

<div>
 @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
 @Model.TEE.GOLF_COURSE.COURSE_NAME
</div>

<table class="table form-group">
<tr>
    <th>Hole Number </th>

    @for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {

    <th>@Model.HOLE_SCORE.ElementAt(i).HOLE_NUMBER</th>
    }

</tr>
</table>
@section Scripts {
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

}

The messages that I’ve seen do not appear to make sense as other pages within my application work:

```
The type or namespace TM470FinalProject could not be found (are you missing a using directive or reference assembly).
```

And

```
 The name 'model' does not exist in the current context.
```

For the above example: If I remove the table from the view the above messages are still there, but the `@Model.TEE.GOLF_COURSE.COURSE_NAME`  displays the name of the course as I expect.

The issue I believe is the `ElementAt(i)` code:

`@Model.HOLE_SCORE.ElementAt(i).HOLE_NUMBER`

This is where I don’t understand why it is failing as I have another view that uses similar code and works fine (but on the web server still flags the 2 messages above).

ALso when I wrote the Razor view on my local machine the intellisense gave me the ElementAt option.

View:

```
@model TM470FinalProject.Areas.GolfApp.Models.TEE

@{
   String s = ViewBag.golfcourse.COURSE_NAME;
   int ttlPar;
   int ttlYards;
 }
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Edit Tee: " + s ;
}

<h2>@s</h2>

<h3>Edit Tee: @Model.TEE_NAME </h3>

<table class="table">
<tr>
   <th>Hole Number </th>
      @for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++)
     {
     <th>  @Model.HOLE_DETAILS.ElementAt(i).HOLE_NUMBER</th>
     }
</tr>
</table>
```

In my models they have similar definitions:

`public virtual ICollection<HOLE_SCORE> HOLE_SCORE { get; set; }`

`public virtual ICollection<HOLE_DETAILS> HOLE_DETAILS { get; set; }`

When I attach the debugger I get the following output when navigating to the first view:

```
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' in Microsoft.CSharp.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' in System.Core.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' in System.Web.Mvc.dll
```

My view webconfig shows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
<configSections>
<sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
<section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
<section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
<namespaces>
<add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
<add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
<add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
<add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
<add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
<add namespace="TM470FinalProject" />
</namespaces>
</pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>

<appSettings>
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
</appSettings>

<system.webServer>
<handlers>
<remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
<add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
</handlers>
</system.webServer>

<system.web>
<compilation>
<assemblies>
<add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
</assemblies>
</compilation>
</system.web>
```

It works locally, and on the webserver one page works fine with similar code so I am at a loss to explain why this is occurring.

I would be grateful for any help/direction in resolving this. Also, do you know how I can retrieve the stack trace for the exceptions the debugger generated? (Im new to asp.net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It confused me as I couldn't understand why it worked locally and not on the webserver.. so I added the following line to the shared error (Views\Shared\Error.cshtml )page: 
    `<p>@Model.Exception.Message</p>`

The web page then displayed the additional information on the error page:

`Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: index`

Again, this shouldn't have occurred as the data that populates the collection is created via a trigger on my database. I began to think about sending the data via the Viewbag and added a count of the scores for when the page renders:

`@ViewBag.hole_scores.Count`

Locally this returned the 18 as expected, but on the webserver it was returning 0.

I recalled when I first published my application to Azure that I had to set up a database in the portal as I couldn't export/copy my local database. Unfortunately my script for the database build seems to have lost the Trigger code, hence when I was created a new object it was not populating the collection as I expected.

After a week of shouting at the dam computer it all comes down to user error and not having the database build script set up correctly.